# How to ensure covariance matrix is positive semi definite in linear dynamical model learning?

Tags: covariance, expectation-maximization, kalman-filter, linear-dynamical-system

I am trying to learn a linear dynamical model for a data using expectation-maximization algorithm. The model is defined as follows:
$$x_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0 ,\Sigma_0)$$
$$ x_{t+1} = Fx_t + w_t, \hspace{7pt} w_t\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu^s ,Q) $$
$$y_t = Hx_t+v_t, \hspace{7pt} v_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu^o,R) $$
where $x_t$ represents the the state vector at time $t$, $y_t$ is the observation vector at time $t$. All the parameters of the LDM remain constant over time. The parameters are estimated using EM algorithm as given [here](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/course04/tr-96-2.pdf). $w_t$ and $v_t$ in the linked paper are zero mean, so the expressions were modified appropriately.
After the maximisation step of each iteration, the covariance matrix of the observation noise $R$, is not necessarily coming out to be positive semi-definite. Is it guaranteed that the covariance matrix obtained after the maximisation step is positive semi-definite?

If yes, then what could I have been possibly doing wrong. 
If no, then what are the possible solutions here?

The expression for the observation noise covariance matrix in the maximisation step is given by:

$$
R = \frac{1}{T}(\Gamma_1 - H_{new} \Gamma_2^\intercal - \mu^o_{new} \zeta_1^\intercal  )
$$
where $H_{new}$ is the newly estimated matrix that maps the state space vector to the observation vector, $T$ are the number of observations, $\mu^o$ is the newly estimated mean of the observation noise,
$$ 
\Gamma_1 =  \sum_t y_ty_t^\intercal 
$$
$$ \Gamma_2 = \sum_t y_t \hat{x}_{t|T}^\intercal $$
$\hat{x}_{t|T}$ are the estimated state vectors using Kalman smoothing given all the $T$ observation vectors.
$$ \zeta = \sum_t y_t $$

The snippet for the above expression for $R$ from the above linked paper is shown below:

[image]

In the snippet, the observation noise is zero mean, so the last term in the expression of $R$ is missing. Also it uses $C$ for $H$

A similar problem is being experienced when estimating the covariance matrix $Q$.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you wrote our your model, or just said more. I don't think this is enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: If $x$ is the state and $H$ maps the state to the observation, why is $H$ hitting $y$ and not $x$? What is that middle term for? Is $R$ the marginal covariance of the observations, or is it conditional on the current state? If the latter, why not subtract the expected emission $H\hat x_{t|T}$ from the observed emission inside the first term?

Comment: You could get some ideas here:  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2ff5/5b99d6d94d331670719bb1df1827b4d502a7.pdf